# Mouse and keyboard not working - 18.04 on Raspberrry Pi 4

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, mouse, raspberrypi

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a

- RPi Model 4, 8 Gb
- Dell keyboard
- Generic mouse
- Kubuntu desktop installed

All was working fine, including mouse and keyboard, until a few days ago. No known action on my part that created problem which is:

- I can log in in headless mode via SSH terminal - no issues in command line mode
- When I try to log in via Windows 10 remote desktop things proceed as normal until after the KDE background opens and asks for my password as normal for network access. After entering my password, the system does not continue to load and does not respond to mouse clicks
- When I connect the mouse and keyboard directly to the RPi along with an HDMI monitor, the system boots as normal in that mode, normal Ubuntu background appears. However there is no response to mouse movement/clicks or keyboard.

I have searched AskUbuntu and other sites and found some similar symptoms. Here is what I have tried so far - and without any success:

- `lsusb` in headless mode via SSH shows the mouse and keyboard as present and the status changes if I disconnect them
- The Rpi works fine with another SD card with 18.04 - mouse and keyboard work via Remote Desktop as normal.
  Direct connection of mouse/keyboard and HDMI to RPi also work as normal with that 18.04 SD card
- Ran update/upgrade.
- Reinstalled `xrdp`.
- Installed `xserver-xorg-input-all`.
- My last attempt was per suggestion on this AskUbuntu site:
- I ran the following commands:

  ```
  sudo ubuntu-drivers devices.
  sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall.   
  sudo apt-get update --fix-missing.  
  sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all.  
  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y.  
  sudo shutdown -r now this is to shutdown and restart.
  ```

So, I am stalled and out of ideas. I am assuming it is not a hardware issue since the RPi works as normal with another 18.04 SD card. I am still too new to Ubuntu to know what to try next and look forward to any help and suggestions. I have spent a lot of time installing ROS and other software on the SD card that is causing this problem and really hope not to start over again. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this appears to be a user account issue!

On a hunch I created a new user with sudo privileges and logged in as that user. No issues with Ubuntu loading the KDE desktop, and the mouse/keyboard worked as normal.

I am now starting to figure out how to fix my existing account.